# Icon element shows over bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

The dropdown menu shows under icon element:

[image]

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="kt-portlet__head-toolbar mr-3 pull-right">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <span class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon btn-icon-md" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i style="padding: 0" class="la la-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <a>Mark as completed</a>
      <a>Edit</a>
      <a>Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please revise the demo above so it shows your problem. There's no indication of what's causing it in your code.